# Luis the bad intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I defined one intent, "getPayment" with many utterances (lang fr):
"What are my last payments"
"have i new payment ?"
"can i see my last payments"
....

But when i test my model, with this utterance : "What are doing today ?" or "what is the weather like today", my intent "getPayment" is returned with a hight score (~0.90).

How can i solve my problem ? I would like to the intent "None" to be returned. i will not defined all utterances/case possible in the intent "None" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to train your `LUIS` model with some "None" examples.

Giving it training examples won't limit what text will trigger the "None" intent, but it will help the other Intents (for example your "getPayment") fire more accurately.

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: It's about LUIS which is software commonly used by programmers doing language processing, it should be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)