# My utterance is getting the "none" intent instead the intent I created in LUIS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have two intents, "PAV" and "None", but for some reason the utterance I added to "PAV" intent is getting "None" predicted intent.

Ps: I retrain my application already.

[image: The chat test (image)]

[image: The only utterance I have (image)]

[image: I have 6 utterances in None intent, and the app was retrained already]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Luis the bad intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715665/luis-the-bad-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might occur because LUIS used POS tagging for doing classification. Try adding some utterances (not pav) for None intent and retrain again.

Comment: Hi Haritha, thank for your feedback.
But, I already have 6 utterances in None intent, and still not working the way I wanted. I added the image with the None utterances if you wanna see it.

Comment: you need to keep training PAV then

Comment: Hi guys!
Ezequiel, thank you. You made me realise that I need to add more utterances to PAV intent, then it'll get the right intent.
So that's work pretty fine.